# Angular 6 Dependency Injection Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular6

I have a cross-platform Angular app, I need to check the platform the App is running on and then decide to inject services based on this info. Here is my structure:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
     {
       provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
       useFactory: configFactory,
       deps: [ConfigService],
       multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: UserService,
      useFactory: userServiceFactory,
      deps: [
        ConfigService
      ],
      multi: true
    },

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Config factory returns a Promise:

```
export function configFactory(configService: ConfigService): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       Device.getInfo().then(info => {
          configService.platform = info.platform; // it either ios or web
       });
    });
  }
}
```

The configService.platform is required to make a decision about the UserService provider and hence I have factory method for it:

```
const userServiceFactory = (configService: ConfigService): any => {
    if(configService.platform === 'ios') {
        return new UserServiceDevice()
    } else {
        return new UserWebServiceWeb();
    }
  }
```

The config service initializes correctly, but before it completes the growerServiceFactory runs and get config.platform to be undefined, so it essentially does not wait for configFactory resolve even after setting ConfigService as a dependency. How do I achieve this ? Is there a better approach for this scenarios ?

Comment: First, why are you using `multi: true`? Do you have multiple instances of `ConfigService` and `UserService`? Second, `configFactory` should return instance of `ConfigService` i think, i.e. it should be `Promise<ConfigService>`, and fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving this at module instantiation time, why not make the service itself more flexible? I know this doesn't answer your original question but it may solve your problem.

The modified UserService:

```
class PlatformAgnosticUserService implements IUserService {
   private service: IUserService;

   constructor(
      private _PLAT : Platform,
      private mobileUserService: MobileUserService,
      private webUserService: WebUserService
   ) {
      if (this._PLAT.is('ios') || this._PLAT.is('android'))
      {
         this.service = mobileUserService;
      }
      else
      {
         this.service = webUserService;
      }
   }

   userCreate(param: any) {
      this.service.userCreate(param);
   }

}
```

I know it's not as nice, but it's the best I can come up with, cheers.

**Old Answer Below**

I think you may be over-complicating things. Why not simplify to this:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: UserService,
      useFactory: userServiceFactory,
      deps: [],
      multi: true
    },

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this:

```
    const growerServiceFactory = (configService: ConfigService): () => Promise<any> => {
return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(
       resolve => {
         Device.getInfo().then(info => {
            return new UserServiceDevice();
       },
       () => {
         return new UserWebServiceWeb()
       });
    });
  }
```

Not sure if you're using the config service for anything else, but at least in this case it can be "skipped".

Comment: Thank you for helping, This is the first thing I tried but it looks like Promise based factory doesn't work for regular providers. I have noticed it only works for APP_INITIALIZER tokens.

Comment: What framework are you using for local deploy, nativescript?

Comment: This is a web app built on Angular 6(typescript), now I am trying to convert this into a Hybrid app using Capacitor(Ionic) for ios native bridge.